# How to submit one html form to difference actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have small form and links created like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.selectform.submit();">Contact</a> | <a href="#">Message</a>

<form  name="selectform"  action="save.php" method="post" target="_blank">
 Name: <input type="text" name="test"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub"/>
</form>
```

When I click "Contact" link, form submit correctly, And If I click "Message" link how to set this form submit to another url

for an example: if i click "Message" link, I want to submit form to edit.php and without using traget="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

You can change the form action using attr() method of jquery,
For example

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
   $('#formId').attr('action', 'page1').submit();
});


$('#link2').click(function(){
   $('#formId').attr('action', 'page2').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.selectform.submit();">Contact</a> | <a href="#" onclick="document.selectform.action='edit.php'; document.selectform.submit();">Message</a>

<form  name="selectform"  action="save.php" methode="post" target="_blank">
 Name: <input type="text" name="test"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

Change in **HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="msgSubmit">Message</a>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#msgSubmit').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();   
   $('form[name="selectform"]').attr('action','edit.php')
                               .removeAttr('target')
                               .submit();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick` event

```
<script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('form1').action = action;
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
</script>

...

   <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('page1.php')" value="submit 1">Contact</a> 
   <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('page2.php')" value="submit 2" >Message</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some modification in your code.
please check and let me know.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myaction('save.php');">Contact</a> | <a href="#" onclick="return myaction('edit.php');">Message</a>

<form id="selectform_id" name="selectform" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
 Name: <input type="text" name="test"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myaction(actn){
    document.getElementById("selectform_id").action = actn;
    document.selectform.submit();
}
</script>
```